# is selection sort faster than insertion for big arrays?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficency of Insertion Sort vs Bubble sort vs Selection sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887629/efficency-of-insertion-sort-vs-bubble-sort-vs-selection-sort)

is selection sort faster than insertion for big arrays? When its in the worstest case?

I know insertion be faster than selection, but for large arrays and in the worstest case?

Comment: I is talking about large arrays tho sir

Comment: Write a program and test it. And then say us here answer for this question please.

Comment: The larger the arrays, the more important the asymptotic O() behavior is and the less important become the costs of individual operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of the array involved is rarely of much consequence.

The real question is the speed of comparison vs. copying. The time a selection sort will win is when a comparison is a *lot* faster than copying. Just for example, let's assume two fields: a single int as a key, and another megabyte of data attached to it.

In such a case, comparisons involve only that single int, so it's really fast, but copying involves the entire megabyte, so it's almost certainly quite a bit slower.

Since the selection sort does a lot of comparisons, but relatively few copies, this sort of situation will favor it. The insertion sort does a lot more copies, so in a situation like this, the slower copies will slow it down quite a bit.

As far as worst case for a insertion sort, it'll be pretty much the opposite -- anything where copying is fast, but comparison is slow. There are a few more cases that favor insertion as well, such as when elements might be slightly scrambled, but each is still within a short distance of its final location when sorted.

If the data doesn't provide a solid indication in either direction, chances are pretty decent that insertion sort will work out better.

Comment: This is not correct, the size of the array is N, which is related to O(N) . if the algo has O(N*N) complexity, then the size of the array is most important.

Comment: @AlexWien: Yes, but in this case we're comparing algorithms that are *both* O(N*N). The size of the array would be important if we were comparing algorithms with different complexity (e.g., O(N*N) to O(N log N), but essentially none when comparing selection sort to insertion sort.

Comment: Even then the Big O notation does not help you. because c1*O(N) can be greater than c2*O(N*N). the big O notation does not consider the factor c. In practise it is a implementation detail: If you can use memcopy then you can move 1000 elements faster that two swap 2 elements

Comment: @AlexWien: That's theoretically true, but in practice something like Introsort or merge sort imposes fairly minimal overhead, so for internal sorting, big-O does actually track pretty closely with real life.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Comparisons_to_other_sorting_algorithms),

> In general, insertion sort will write to the array O(n2) times,
>   whereas selection sort will write only O(n) times. For this reason
>   selection sort may be preferable in cases where writing to memory is
>   significantly more expensive than reading, such as with EEPROM or
>   flash memory.

That's going to be true regardless of the array size. In fact, the difference will be more pronounced as the arrays get larger.

Comment: @user1516883 you cannot tell which is faster, this is machine dependent. The memory acess, is important. a memcopy moving the whole array can be fateer than a single swap of two entries. Thats the reason why the LinkedList in java is slower then the ArrayList.

Comment: No this is not independent of the array size. You forget that O(N) means c*O(N) and when using memcopy in insertion sort then c is very low.  c1*O(n) can be greater than c2 * O(N*N)

Comment: @user1516883: Yes, in general insertion sort will be faster. However, it depends on the speed of memory access. The Wikipedia article really does explain things quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion sort, if well implemented use memcpy() to move the other values. So it depends on the processor, the cache speed (first level 2nd level chache), the cache size, when one algo becomes faster then the other.

I remember an implementations (was it java?) where one algo was used when the number of elements  did not exceed a specific hard coded threshold, otherwise another algo was used.

So, you simply have to measure it.
The big O notation is for small and medium array a bit misleading, then O(N) means c * O(N).
And the factor c influences the total execution time.